# Using MEssaging Queue like AMQP, ZMQ, Kafka etc with Rocksdb

Tags: rocksdb

I have gone through some material, talks and some documentation on rocksdb.
I find it interesting for some use cases. I would like to understand how it can be used to populate data using message queues like AMQP, ZMQ or Kafka.

I've not gone through individual files on github, in case there is any explanation on this.
Request you to share your thoughts/experiences on the same.

Thanks